# Generating a Square, Saw, and Sine Sample and Writing to an AIFF file - big-endian Issues

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, swift2

Trying to generate a square, saw, and sin wav in code and then save to an AIFF file based off Chris Adam's Learning Core Audio book. I have it working but I'm confused about why I don't need to convert the sample to `.bigEndian` in Swift but you need to in Obj-C?

Here's what the working code in Obj-C looks like:

```
SInt16 sample = CFSwapInt16HostToBig ((( i / wavelengthInSamples) * 
SHRT_MAX *2) - SHRT_MAX);
```

Here's what the working code in Swift2 looks like:

```
var sample = Int16(((Double(i) / wavelengthInSamples) 
* Double(Int16.max) * 2) - Double(Int16.max))
```

Here's what the Swift playground graph looks like if I leave off `.bigEndian`
[image: swift playground saw wave]

If I add `.bigEndian` after converting to `Int16()` and send to AudioFileWriteBytes, the generated audio does not sound correct:

```
var sample = Int16(((Double(i) / wavelengthInSamples) 
* Double(Int16.max) * 2) - Double(Int16.max)).bigEndian
AudioFileWriteBytes(audioFile, 0, Int64(sampleCount * 2), &bytesToWrite, &sample)
```

[Full source here](https://gist.github.com/justinlevi/7a846070ee6e7e245cc3): https://gist.github.com/justinlevi/7a846070ee6e7e245cc3

Here are links to the generated audio files. The volume on the square wave is really low for some reason too.

- [Square Wave](http://justinlevi.com/440.0-square.aif)
- [Saw Wave](http://justinlevi.com/440.0-saw.aif)
- [Sine Wave](http://justinlevi.com/440.0-sin.aif)

**Follow up question:** Why would the square wave be soo much quieter versus the saw or the sin waves?

*SOURCE: Adamson, Chris; Avila, Kevin (2012-04-03). Learning Core Audio: A Hands-On Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS (Kindle Locations 1063-1073). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.*

Comment: in the Swift version, if you do not add `.bigEndian` and you write the audio file, does it sound correct?

Comment: Yes, if I do NOT add `.bigEndian` then the wave sounds correct but that is my question. Why would you need to convert the sample to .bigEndian in Obj-C but not in Swift? 

Especially when AIFF requires Big Endian samples.

Comment: this is pretty interesting, every indication is that you should have to convert to big-endian, weird... re: the audio file that is output, using your gist I couldn't get it to write a file that could be opened by Quicktime or Logic... if you have a minute to do so could you update your gist to write a complete file? I'm interested in seeing the resulting waveform when opened up in an editor - thank you!

Comment: Posted the entire project here: https://github.com/justinlevi/CAToneGeneratorSwift

Comment: Added links to the audio files above as well.

Comment: Note, the project is built with XCode7 Beta and Swift2

Comment: awesome, pulling the files (and the project) now!

Comment: wild, the output AIFF has exactly the same waveform / shape as the graph we see in playground (without big-endianness)

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried the Objective-C version in Xcode 7? (with-and-without `CFSwapInt16HostToBig()`)

Comment: this might be worth filing a radar about  :)  http://bugreport.apple.com - maybe something changed in Foundation, or in the Audio Toolbox framework, something that hasn't been communicated that automatically does the endian byte-swapping for file types that require it? so many possibilities, but I'm not sure there's much more we'll figure out here - unless some fresh eyes get on this and spot something we haven't!

Comment: you know who else might be interested in this: Chris Adamson   :)  you could ping him on twitter with a link to this question

Comment: :) I actually reached out to Chris first but realized he probably gets about a million silly questions like this so thought I'd leave him alone and try to help out someone else down the line. @fqdn thanks for looking into this. I'll keep looking at this a bit more and will file a radar if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh... @jaybers totally made me realize that the AIFF files were being written as littleEndian which is why the graphs looked like that. I was seeing those graphs in the playground when I added `.bigEndian` onto the sample. I have updated the github project above and now everything renders as expected. Square wave is also as loud as the other samples...

[image: Big Endian AIFF Graphs]

Here are the new audio files with the .bigEndian Conversion.

- [Big Endian Square Wave](http://justinlevi.com/bigendian_440.0-square.aif)
- [Big Endian Saw Wave](http://justinlevi.com/bigendian_440.0-saw.aif)
- [Big Endian Sine Wave](http://justinlevi.com/bigendian_440.0-sin.aif)

Answer (score 1):

For your follow up question, the average RMS power of a square wave is higher than a sine wave.  The square wave spends most of its time at its maximum peak amplitude.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) and [stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/square-wave-sine-wave-is-more-audible) for more information.

Your sine, saw, and square wave files you uploaded are not the waveforms you are expecting.  They seem to be repeating functions but the wave forms are not pure.  I opened the wave forms in audacity.  The top is sine.  Middle is saw and bottom is square.   You can see that the amplitude is way down on the square wave (practically inaudible).    If the waveforms were correct, the square wave would be much louder.

[image]

Comment: oh, this is really interesting actually. I didn't think to check the waveforms in Audicity after rendering... Interesting to note that the waves as they are appearing in Audicity are exactly what I'm seeing in the playground when I add .bigEndian to the sample value.